# Terraform GCP service_account vs project vs org

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam, terraform-provider-gcp

i am picking up terraform for GCP and i came across these three resources:

1. [google_service_account_iam_member](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account_iam.html)
2. [google_project_iam_member](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_iam.html)
3. [google_organization_iam_member](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_organization_iam_member.html)

They sound very similar to each other but certainly with some key differences.

I went through their docs but their differences were not absolutely clear to me. Is there any easy way to illustrate the difference between these?

Thanks

Comment: Are you new to both Terraform and GCP? Or are you comfortable with one of them?

Comment: both - i do have reasonable experience with AWS to draw analogies with

Comment: @Rakib - I do not recommend comparing AWS and GCP security. Very different implementations. Where AWS is built around access keys, GCP is built around OAuth Tokens. Even the methods of granting/denying access are very different. Sort of like you speak Japanese and English. You can map single words, but the entire language structure, customs, etc. are different.

Answer (score 4):

Within GCP, there is a hierarchy: Organization, Project, Resource

The IAM policies you mentioned behaves the same; however, works on different levels based on the hierarchy.

For example, the `google_project_iam_member` will update the IAM policy to grant a role to a new member on the project level.

The `google_organization_iam_member` will do the same thing, but on the Organization level (which is a level higher than the project).

Update:

The google_service_account_iam_member will work on every level depending on what you would like the service account to do. You can either have the service account act as an identity or just have it run a certain resouce. A service account can be added on all three levels.

Comment: Can you also expand on what the service account IAM member does compared to the others?

Answer (score 1):

As described before the google_project_iam_member and google_organization_iam_member, are used to manager IAM permission in the project or organization level. You can also manage permission on the folder level.

When, IAM is granted on the org level all folders and projects inherit that permission. When granted in the folder, alll projects and sub folders under that folder will inherit that permission.

Permissions can also be managed at resource level, the google_service_account_iam_member allow to grant permission to manage the service account and use the service account in the service account level. That helpful when you want to grant more restricted permissions and grant access to a single service account instead of all service accounts from the project.

Thanks,
Eduardo Ruela